# Firestore queries on Flutter

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

How can I use the .where() in FlutterFire to perform queries for Firestore? Because the docs and example doesn't cover this I'm confused. I haven't found other questions on this here so I hope I'm not asking duplicate.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Example below go through every document in the collection 'fields', and filter on 'grower`. There is no documentation on that, but you may check the source code.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

Firestore.instance.collection('fields').where('grower', isEqualTo: 1)
    .snapshots().listen(
          (data) => print('grower ${data.documents[0]['name']}')
    );
```

From source code:

```
  Query where(
    String field, {
    dynamic isEqualTo,
    dynamic isLessThan,
    dynamic isLessThanOrEqualTo,
    dynamic isGreaterThan,
    dynamic isGreaterThanOrEqualTo,
    bool isNull,
  }) {..}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I couldn't find the syntax for it!

Comment: This helps. Thanks. Documentation needs to be improved on the plugin.

Comment: @grepLines I'm also facing a similar issue. I'm following your mention solution but, in my case, it's returning empty data. Here my StackOverflow post link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50235230/how-to-fetch-data-from-firestore-in-flutter

Comment: Hello, i'd like to know if you can do 'where' filtering for multiple values, putting more than one value in the clausule. Example: where age is high than x, and wheigh is less than, etc.

Comment: Jorge you can't query with range over different values

Comment: Hey @Jorge and other people who are still looking for the multiple conditions query, I understand that this is possible using multiple `where` clauses.

Comment: > Show me the code:

    @override
      Stream<List<UserFeedEntity>> userfeeds(String userID) {
        return firestore.collection(path).where("userID", isEqualTo: userID).where("projectID", isEqualTo: "sc_demo_project1").snapshots().map((snapshot) {
          return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
            return UserFeedEntity(
              doc['projectID'],
              doc['installationID'],
              doc['userID'],
              doc['feeds'].cast<String>(),
            );
          }).toList();
        });
      }

Comment: @JorgeVieira Yes you can use multiple where queries. See this link => https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this! I had the same issue not finding this example!

Comment: if you want a documentation for firestore in flutter, check my article https://petercoding.com/firebase/2020/04/04/using-cloud-firestore-in-flutter/ @Purus

Comment: Thanks @PeterHaddad for the info.

Comment: If I have mapped my firebase data to a model, can I use that model's fields with typesafety in the where function?

Answer (score 18):

#### Update (Null safety code)

Since lot of classes are now either deprecated or completely removed, use this code for Flutter 2.0 and above.

```dart
final querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('employees')
    .limit(10)
    .where('age', isGreaterThan: 30)
    .get();

for (var doc in querySnapshot.docs) {
  // Getting data directly
  String name = doc.get('name');
  
  // Getting data from map
  Map<String, dynamic> data = doc.data();
  int age = data['age'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this if you use streambuilder

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: feed.where('uid', isEqualTo: 'aaaaaaaaaaaaa').snapshots(),
        builder: (_, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Column(
              children: snapshot.data.docs
                  .map((e) => itemGrid(
                        e.data()['username'],
                        e.data()['uid'],
                        e.data()['uavatarUrl'],
                        e.data()['imageUrl'],
                        e.data()['desc'],
                      ))
                  .toList(),
            );
          } else {
            print('null');
            return Container();
          }
        }));
```

Answer (score 1):

**Example data**

To get started, write some data about cities so we can look at different ways to read it back:

```
final cities = db.collection("cities");
final data1 = <String, dynamic>{
  "name": "San Francisco",
  "state": "CA",
  "country": "USA",
  "capital": false,
  "population": 860000,
  "regions": ["west_coast", "norcal"]
};
cities.doc("SF").set(data1);

final data2 = <String, dynamic>{
  "name": "Los Angeles",
  "state": "CA",
  "country": "USA",
  "capital": false,
  "population": 3900000,
  "regions": ["west_coast", "socal"],
};
cities.doc("LA").set(data2);

final data3 = <String, dynamic>{
  "name": "Washington D.C.",
  "state": null,
  "country": "USA",
  "capital": true,
  "population": 680000,
  "regions": ["east_coast"]
};
cities.doc("DC").set(data3);

final data4 = <String, dynamic>{
  "name": "Tokyo",
  "state": null,
  "country": "Japan",
  "capital": true,
  "population": 9000000,
  "regions": ["kanto", "honshu"]
};
cities.doc("TOK").set(data4);

final data5 = <String, dynamic>{
  "name": "Beijing",
  "state": null,
  "country": "China",
  "capital": true,
  "population": 21500000,
  "regions": ["jingjinji", "hebei"],
};
cities.doc("BJ").set(data5);
```

**Simple queries**

1. The following query returns all cities with state CA:

```
// Create a reference to the cities collection
final citiesRef = db.collection("cities");

// Create a query against the collection.
final query = citiesRef.where("state", isEqualTo: "CA");
```

2. The following query returns all the capital cities:

```
final capitalcities =
    db.collection("cities").where("capital", isEqualTo: true);
```

**Execute a query**

After creating a query object, use the get() function to retrieve the results:

```
db.collection("cities").where("capital", isEqualTo: true).get().then(
      (res) => print("Successfully completed"),
      onError: (e) => print("Error completing: $e"),
    );
```

Refer the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#dart) for more information