# Flutter firestore plugin can't able to fetch data with combination of where and isEqualTo

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I have a collection by name "trips" in Firestore. The data format is something like this

[image]

I'm trying to access documents of that Collection by using below code.

**First way**

```
try {
  Firestore.instance
      .collection("trips")
      .where("createdByName", isEqualTo: "Suresh")
      .snapshots
      .listen((data) => print('Firestore response1: ${data.documents}'));
} catch (e){
  print('Caught Firestore exception1');
  print(e);
}
```

**Second way**

```
try {
  Firestore.instance.collection("trips").where("createdByName", isEqualTo: "Suresh").getDocuments().then((data) {
    print('Firestore response2: , ${data.documents}');
  });
} catch (e){
  print('Caught Firestore exception2');
  print(e);
}
```

But, none of the above two ways is working. Don't know what I'm doing wrong.

---

One thing I've noticed whenever I'm removing the `where("createdByName", isEqualTo: "Suresh")` part from the query it's working fine. But, the moment I include that part query is returning an empty result.

Comment: What does "none is working" mean exactly? If you get an error message, please add it to the question.

Comment: It's you!!! What a coincident...  In my above sample code in 2 ways I'm trying to access that collection(trips) data. But none of those 2 ways are working. Also, not getting any error & just getting empty data. Updated my post for more clarity

Comment: I guess I can't help. I only used Realtime Database so far. If you don't get any data, then perhaps just the query is wrong or you might need to create an index on the server to be able to filter by `createdByName`

Comment: I also feel somewhere in my query is wrong. But, can't able to fig out what's exactly in my query is wrong. Anyway, no problem. I'll try to fig. out.

Comment: currently snapshots is to be given as snapshots() else listen is causing error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after two days of breaking my brain for this silly thing... this is the answer to the issue... `.where('trip.createdByName', isEqualTo: "Suresh")`

And, the full queries are like this...

**First way**

```
Firestore.instance.collection('trips')
  .where('trip.createdByName', isEqualTo: "Suresh")
  .snapshots.listen(
      (data){
        data.documents.forEach((doc) => print( 'Firestore response1 : ${doc.data.toString()}' ));
      }
  );
```

**Second way**

```
Firestore.instance.collection("trips")
  .where("trip.createdByName", isEqualTo: "Suresh")
  .getDocuments().then((string) {
    string.documents.forEach((doc) => print("Firestore response2: ${doc.data.toString()}" ));
  });
```

Hope, this will be a help. :)

Comment: Hello, i'd like to know if is possible to add more than one where clausule, for example, where 'createdbyName' isEqualTo suresh AND/OR where date islowthan.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the screenshot is accurate but it looks like you have a `trip` node as well. That would put the hierarchy as `trips.trip.createdByName`, no? If so, it's likely that the `where` clause is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tested this but still, I'm getting no result. I think this is not the case. :(

Comment: OMG!!! Actually, the solution is ```.where('trip.createdByName', isEqualTo: "Suresh")```. From last two days, I'm breaking my head on this small thing. Your small suggestion spark this in my mind.