# Cycle through firestore query result

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a query which defines the documents I'm looking for, how do I cycle through them and add them to the list?

query and cycle so far:

```
// Create a reference to the cities collection
val facRef = firestoreInstance.collection("faculty")
// Create a query against the collection.
val query = facRef.whereEqualTo("university", list[position].ID)
// Cycle
listFac.clear()
for (document in query) {
    val fac = Faculty()
    fac.ID = document.id
    fac.Desc = document["Desc"].toString()
    listFac.add(fac)
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with this code? Using `listFac.add(fac)` is this what you are doing? Aren't you adding objects of type `Faculty` to the `listFac` list?

Comment: @AlexMamo the line `document in query` is the error, `query` is underlined in red. Says for loop needs to have an iterator method

Comment: "is the error" ok, so what is the exact error that you are talking about?

Comment: @AlexMamo it just says the loop needs an iterator method

Comment: Please paste the exact entire error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call a query you need to give it time to retrieve the results, for example, do what you want to do in the snapshots method

```
for (document in query.snapshots) {
val fac = Faculty()
fac.ID = document.id
fac.Desc = document["Desc"].toString()
listFac.add(fac)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

A query doesn't immediately contain the documents from the database. You need to first tell it to retrieve those documents, for example by calling `query.snapshots`:

```
for (document in query.snapshots) {
    val fac = Faculty()
    fac.ID = document.id
    fac.Desc = document["Desc"].toString()
    listFac.add(fac)
}
```

Also see:

- [Firestore queries on Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48937864/firestore-queries-on-flutter)
- the [documentation for Cloud Firestore in FlutterFire](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/cloud_firestore)
- this [tutorial on building a Flutter app with Firestore](https://flutter.institute/firebase-firestore/).