# How to search a value in Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have Firestore database that looks like this

```
- user
    - (document id)
        - userId: Rsa245156.....
        - username: user67
        - age: 23
        - address: Flamboyan Street No. 24
        - picture_path: ......
```

I created a userId from the userId that is in Firebase Auth, so when the logged in user opens the profile tab, the application will look for the userId in Firestore Database that is the same as the user userId that is logged in, and load all fields that are associated with that userId.

The question is, how do I find the same userId, and load all fields or only the "username" field? I use flutter

Comment: I have followed this method https://stackoverflow.com/q/48937864/10094689 but 'listen' is not defined for the class 'Function'

Comment: @anangfaturrohman Yes, you are right. That answer was incorrect. I updated it there. It should work now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firestore queries on Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48937864/firestore-queries-on-flutter)

Comment: Thanks, does that method will check in every documents ?

Comment: Which database you are using Real time or cloud?

Comment: Realtime Database

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya could you please help me, i tried every solution in stackoverflow, but every solution just return the type of variable, not value inside Firestore Database, it just return like ```userInstance of "_Random"```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve using current users data(email). orderByChild select the field and equalTo method compare the value.

i hope that following example help you more.

```
FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser(); // get the current users details
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
ref.child('user')
    .orderByChild('userId')// userId contain the email id of users
    .equalTo(user.email) // if you login your user using email ID
    .onValue
    .listen((event) {
  DataSnapshot data = event.snapshot;
  var keys = data.value.keys;
  var todo = data.value;
  for (var key in keys) {
    _email= todo[key]['userId']; // get the email id
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, i will try it

Answer (score 0):

How you want to use Firestore you can user like this code below. Old Firebase is another class.

```
Firestore _firestore = Firestore.instance;
firestore.collection('user')
        .where('userId', isEqualTo: user.reference)
        .snapshots().listen((snapshot) {
           snapshot.documents.forEach((doc) {
              doc.data['username']
      })
    })
```