# How to work with query in firebase with flutter?

Tags: arrays, database, firebase, flutter, dart

I want to create a query which contains all the documents in the free collection which have in the field list the value item2

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firestore queries on Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48937864/firestore-queries-on-flutter)

Comment: Lookup a tutorial on Firebase and Flutter. There are loads of them.

Comment: suggest me a one, please

Comment: StackOverflow is a site for problems and solutions, not a forum to ask for recommendations. The tutorials are literally a Google search away.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query in StreamBuilder and retrieve data through it.

stream: Firestore.instance.collection('free').snapshots()

In stream we can get all documents.

Finally we can get item  by accessing first document .ie data[0].In the first document we will get ['list'] and in that list we will get the first item which is item 4.

snapshot.data[0]['list'][0]