# Failed assertion while trying to get single document from firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

**I am trying to get simply a document from my firebase collection**
but i get this error: Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(Error 5, FIRFirestoreErrorDomain, No document to update
I have a document with the document id i checked it by printing
and this is my code:

```
  void updateBalanceOfSender() async {
    var docID;
    Firestore.instance
        .collection('balance')
        .where('user', isEqualTo: loggedInUser.email)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((data) =>
            data.documents.forEach((doc) => print(docID = doc.documentID)));
    _firestore
        .collection('balance')
        .document(docID)
        .updateData({'balance': '1'});
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the wrong arguments to where method.
Use the code below:

```
 void updateBalanceOfSender() async {   

    var document = await Firestore.instance      
    .collection('balance')      
    .where(“user”,isEqualTo: loggedInUser.email);

    print(document);

}
```

Have a look at [this](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore) to see how to perform queries.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48937864/firestore-queries-on-flutter)  might also help.

Comment: actually i would like to get the document id by document.documentID but after i fixing the code as you said i get this error ; Invalid argument: Instance of 'CupertinoDatePickerMode'

Comment: I don’t see a DatePicker in your code. Please update the code you posted for this error but from what I can see from your question and the error you’re getting, My code has to solve the problem. The where method will return the document where  the user field has loggedInUser.email value and you can get the id with document.id

Comment: *you can get the document id with document.documentID