# Flutter Firestore, sorting data by date

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

This is my search code. I am using this code for get Card from firestore. I am trying to set sorting by date my cards.

How can I do that. Thanks for help.

```
class SearchService {
      List<Future<QuerySnapshot>> searchByName() {
        return [
          Firestore.instance
              .collection('dis')
              .where('no')
              .getDocuments(),
    
    
        ];
      }
    }
```

Comment: What is 'no' in you're query? Btw look at this for queries in flutter firestore: Flutter Firestore https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48937864/firestore-queries-on-flutter

Comment: its string number like 123456

Comment: So how in this, you are sorting according to date??

Comment: I can change 'no' to timestamp but I am still dont know how can I sort by date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "where" clause isn't going to sort the query results for you.  You will need to use [orderBy](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/orderBy.html) for that.  You will also need to know the name of the date field to use for ordering, as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#ordering).

```
          Firestore.instance
              .collection('dis')
              .orderBy('date')
              .getDocuments(),
```

If you don't have a field that stores a date for each document, you won't be able to order the results.

Comment: Moreover, if run into index error, you need to create an index on your own in firebase.

Comment: you can change the order of sort by adding   orderBy('date', descending: true),